# Orion ContextBroker: Notify to Custom WebService

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to integrate Orion notification with a custom WebService, but I'm not able to get data in the WebService.

I have the subscription defined like I subscribed Cygnus, but with WebService url.

Orion's output:

```
DEBUG@10:34:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[299]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'User-Agent: orion/0.23.0 libcurl/7.19.7'
DEBUG@10:34:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[307]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.es:8080'
DEBUG@10:34:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[351]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'Content-length: 3277'
DEBUG@10:34:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[419]: Sending message 174 to HTTP server: sending message of 3518 bytes to HTTP server
INFO@10:34:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[434]: Notification Successfully Sent to xxxxxxxxxxxxx:8080/PruebasREST/webresources/service
INFO@10:34:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[445]: Transaction ended
```

If I do a json POST curl in a console, the WebService is working as expected, but when Orion sends notification there is no response from the WebService.

Does anyone imagine what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was the Accept Header sent by Orion.

The WebService response wasn't the same type than the Accept Header

Thanks to ***LeandroGuillen*** for giving me the clue to know the exact format of Orion's json POST with **accumulator-service.py**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are expecting to receive from your server, but I can tell you that Orion is not expecting anything.

When doing notifications it will send them out and not really care whether there is an HTTP response from the other end.

Comment: The problem is the WebService is not getting anything (or is getting something different than a json POST), so I have some kind of problem to guess the message notification sent by Orion. Orion just logs Header Information, not the message itself

Comment: You could using localhost as notification receiver and use the accumulator-server.py script that is under scripts on Orion's repo. If you get notifications there you should get them somewhere else.
Other option is using wireshark and take a look at your network traffic.

Comment: I could get the message with the accumulator-server.py. But is the same message as I was expecting with the WebService. So I don't know if the problem is because the WebService is in other server. I'm going to deploy the service in the same localhost and try it again

Comment: Is a problem with the WebService, is giving me "406 error". Some kind of problem with the Headers, if I do a curl without headers is getting the json, but if I POST with the Headers I got with accumulator-server.py that POST is not working

Comment: The **problem** in my WebService is the header: **Accept: application/xml, application/json**